# How to reset all checkboxes in a shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Currently have the following code - is there any way in which I can reset all `checkboxes` within this app - regardless of being selected on one tab - or multiple tabs?

So I have introduced a select and deselect all button into the app as well so hopefully that feature will still remain in there?

**code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
  tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
         tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                  width = 12, 
                  height = 800
         )


  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
          )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices =product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `updateCheckboxGroupInput` should work just fine if you get rid of `renderUI`. Generally speaking, `renderUI` with input widgets can get you in all kinds of trouble and should only be used when it is absolutely necessary. Also, try to use `observeEvent` instead of `observe`. It improves readability and avoids unwanted side-effects in the long run.

Comment: I cannot render the UI elements outside of the server function as i would like the elements to be generated through the server - also i need the constant observe running as its the only way it knows which checkboxes have been selected?

Comment: If you cannot avoid `renderUI` that's okay. But if `updateCheckboxGroupInput` should only be applied in response to a button press, use `observeEvent(input$button_id, ...)`. That is exactly what `observeEvent` is made for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on a fixed naming convention for your checkboxes (I added the "chk_"-prefix)

*Edit: distinguish updateCheckboxInput and updateCheckboxGroupInput*

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel"),
    tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
           tabPanel("Visualisation",
                    br(),
                    width = 12, 
                    height = 800
           )
    ),
    column(12, actionButton(inputId ="resetBtn", label = "Reset Selection", icon = icon("times-circle")))
  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("chksingle_all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
            )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("chkgrp_select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("chksingle_all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("chkgrp_checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices =product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$resetBtn, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    resetChksingleInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chksingle*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting single checkboxes:", resetChksingleInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChksingleInputs, updateCheckboxInput, session=session, value = FALSE)

    resetChkgrpInputs <- names(input)[grepl("^chkgrp*", names(input))]
    cat("Resetting checkbox groups:", resetChkgrpInputs, sep = "\n")
    lapply(resetChkgrpInputs, updateCheckboxGroupInput , session=session, selected = character(0))

  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - however this does not reset the checkboxes when you select them across different tabs only when you press select all on a singular tab - mostly because it should be an observe so constantly running instead?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to. On my machine all tabs are cleared.

Comment: One moment i am writing a response in detail below for you

Comment: Okay 0- if you press the initial reset all button it sets everything to being not selected as it starts with all being selected - now if you press 2 checkboxes on the first tab and then 2 on the next tab - then press reset all button it does not reset those checkboxes to being "un selected" it leaves them as they are which is "selected"

Comment: Ah, yes I see. We need to distinguish between `checkboxInput`s and `checkboxGroupInput`s - please see my edit. You might want to wrap the reset procedure in a function to avoid repeating the code (short on time currently).

Comment: Thanks for the input! really useful to see how it works - i think a function for wrapping up the code would be a logical next step

Comment: Just wondering if you had any thoughts on the following situation in the app: if you select some checkboxes on one tab panel, then switch tab panels and press "select all" it will use the Dplyr statement and retain that information and use that as those checkboxes you've selected as the it believes that to be the first instace - is there any way around this? I've used an isolate, reactive Values and even wrapped an ifelse statement on it but no luck - more information is below for the scenario!

Comment: For example - Run the App - Press the button Reset all Checkboxes - Now see the following behaviour - On the "edibles" tab "check" the box titled "bacon", now switch tabs and go on the "Fried" tab and "check" the "Select All" button - this removes the "checked" bacon checkbox we originally checked and uses the "Fried" tab as essentially the first instance of pressing anything - sure you can check whatever you want afterwards, but this behaviour is buggy because of that first Dplyr statement - any work arounds - tried nearly everything i can think of!

Comment: You have exactly the same behaviour in your original code. Accordingly, I think you should open up another question for this. Here it was asked to reset all checkboxes - this is what I provided you with. PS: the problem will be the combination of `observe` (listening to all changes) and `updateCheckboxGroupInput`.

Comment: indeed it would be! thanks for the help on this - i've accepted the answer - but this question is closed as far as i can tell!